# How to hide wordpress default description box?

Tags: wp-admin, admin, excerpt, visual-editor

I'm using custom fields in my wordpress default post area. So i don't want wordpress default description box. 
I mean i dont want this field.

[image]

Instead of description box i want excerpt box there. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use simple one liner with  [remove_post_type_support()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support) :

```
remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
```

Comment: Thanks Bainternet. Its working correctly. But i have problems in adding excerpt(summary) form in the post area. I used this code. Please tell me whats wrong. `if ( function_exists('add_post_type_support') ) 
{
    add_action('init', 'add_post_excerpts');
    function add_post_excerpts() 
    {        
        add_post_type_support( 'post', 'excerpt' );
    }
}`

Comment: make sure excerpt is enabled under screen options tab in upper right corner of edit screen.